# Woher kommt das „ä“ in „bettlägerig“?

Tags: etymology, adjective

Als ich zum ersten Mal das Wort hörte, dachte ich, dass man *bettlegerig* (aus "legen") schreiben sollte. Ich versuche, den Ursprung des „ä“s im Adjektiv *bettlägerig* nachzuvollziehen. Es beschreibt, dass jemand im Bett *liegen* muss (ich glaube alle hier wissen es).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Früher auch *bettrüstig* genannt; von rüsten, ruhen; davon **bettlägerig**, d.h. von **lagern** (anderes Wort für ausruhen) abgeleitet. [<sup>(1)</sup>](http://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=HZREAAAAcAAJ&q=bettl%C3%A4gerig#v=snippet&q=bettl%C3%A4gerig&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

Die Vergangenheitsform von "liegen" ist "lag/lagen" und könnte davon abgeleitet zu **lägerig**" werden. Beim Konjunktiv "läge/lägen" würde es noch offensichtlicher.

Wobei "legen" und "liegen" ja nur die aktive und passive Form der selben "Tätigkeit" sind.

Comment: Dann bezieht es sich auf die Vergangenheit. Demzufolge wäre ["aufgrund von Krankheit im Bett liegen müssend"](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bettl%C3%A4gerig) vielleicht nicht so genaue Definition wie deren Vergangenheit Form. Oder?

Comment: Gibt es eventuell auch eine Zusammengehörigkeit zum `Lager`, die hier in die Wortbildung mit eingeflossen ist?

Comment: Nicht unbedingt, @c.p. Die Imperfekt-Stammform findet sich gerne auch im zugehörigen Nomen: liegen - lag - die Lage. Stehen - stand - der Stand - beständig.

Comment: @SentryRaven: **sehr** guter Punkt! Es gab da ja noch alte Wortvarianten ala Bettstatt, Ruhelager usw. ...